# hrtimer timer mode in hrtimer_init() vs expiry mode in hrtimer_start()

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I'm struggling to understand why we have two modes for the hrtimer. What effect expiry mode in hrtimer_start() (and related functions) has vs timer mode in hrtimer_init()?

Answer (score 0):

In `hrtimer_init(timer, clock_id, mode)`, the only distinction between `HRTIMER_MODE_ABS` and `HRTIMER_MODE_REL` is that the function may replace the `clock_id` value `CLOCK_REALTIME` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` if `HRTIMER_MODE_REL` is used:

```
    /*
     * POSIX magic: Relative CLOCK_REALTIME timers are not affected by
     * clock modifications, so they needs to become CLOCK_MONOTONIC to
     * ensure POSIX compliance.
     */
    if (clock_id == CLOCK_REALTIME && mode & HRTIMER_MODE_REL)
        clock_id = CLOCK_MONOTONIC;
```

In `hrtimer_start(timer, tim, mode)`, `mode & HRTIMER_MODE_REL` indicates that `tim` is relative to the current time.

Comment: My question was between expiry mode in hrtimer_start() and timer mode in hrtimer_init(), and not between ABS and REL.

Comment: @samuzu.pazael Perhaps you should explain what you mean by "expiry mode" and "timer mode" in your question, because you have their association with `hrtimer_start()` amd `hrtimer_init()` swapped over in your comment above when compared to your original question.

Comment: I don't get it. The expiry mode is tied to hrtimer_start() and that's both in my comment and original question. The timer mode is tied to hrtimer_init().

Edit: Here are the function definitions:

void hrtimer_init ( struct hrtimer *   timer,
  clockid_t   clock_id,
  enum hrtimer_mode   mode); <- this is timer mode

int hrtimer_start ( struct hrtimer *   timer,
  ktime_t   tim,
  const enum hrtimer_mode   mode); <- this is expiry mode

My question is simple what is the difference between timer and expiry mode.

Comment: @samuzu.pazael Yes, sorry, that was a braino on my part. I think the "expiry mode" bits are just a sub-set of the "timer mode" bits. Specifically, `HRTIMER_MODE_SOFT` and `HRTIMER_MODE_HARD` are for "soft expiry mode" and "hard expiry mode".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that expiry mode only defines how the expiry time in hrtimer_start() is interpreted, so the only two valid values are HRTIMER_MODE_ABS and HRTIMER_MODE_REL. Also, it seems that, under PREEMPT_RT (before v5.4) there will be a check if HRTIMER_MODE_SOFT (added explicitly) corresponds to the relevant bit in timer mode in hrtimer_init(). As of v5.4 it seems that these two modes have to correspond in these bits.